# RichTextBox enconding on Linux - Mono

Tags: c#, linux, winforms, encoding, mono

My RichTextBox contains a few colored text. His Font is `new Font("Arial", 8.25f, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)0))`

In Windows I don't have any problem.

But in Linux diacritics isn't working. I can see that in Rtf header in Linux is:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033
{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 DejaVu Sans;}}
{\colortbl \red0\green0\blue0;\red0\green0\blue255;}
{\*\generator Mono RichTextBox;}\pard\f0\fs16 
\par

\par

\par

....

D9B1DE9DE\'FDE9\'FD
```

(Copied from Linux terminal)

In Windows it's quite different

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1250\deff0\deflang1029
{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset238{\*\fname Arial;}Arial CE;}}
{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue255;\red255\green69\blue0;\red0\green128\blue0;}

Jak se m\'e1\'9a? \fs17
```

(Copied from VS debug window)

There is so much new lines, though I'm using `Environment.NewLine` and diacritics letters are converted to something like this `D9B1DE9DE\'FDE9\'FD`

I tried change CultureInfo, also change fonts, but no change.

How can I fix it? I'd like have the same font on the both systems.

Thanks for responds.

Answer (score 0):

If the same code has different results on Mono than on .Net, it can be considered as a bug.

Which version of mono are you using? The Winforms have got a few bugs fixed in the last few months.

If you already run the lastest version (2.10.9) you should post your problem on the mono mailing (mono-devel-list[at]lists.ximian.com)

Comment: I'm using the latest version. I don't think so that it is a bug. Cause it change Font to Dajavu in Linux and Mono MacOS on Mac. So I think that it's property of mono. But I cannot found how to change it and also how change the unreasonable encoding. I don't understand why is mono using cp1252. Somebody must deal with it, cause diacritics and special chars are in a lot of languages. But I cannot find anything. And also the duplicit new lines though I'm using Environment.NewLine. But if I will not found any solution. I'll try mail them. Thanks for respond :)

Comment: Arial is not as standard available neither on Mac nor Linux. I suspect the system tries to substitute them.